# A doubt with makeidx and imakeidx

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I was revisiting a .tex file in book style and now I don´t know how the index was created.

I´ve the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}

%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\makeindex[name=people, title=Index, options=-s latex.ist -c, intoc, columns=3]

\begin{document}

We have that a set \index{set} blablablablablablablablablablablabla...

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
%\printindex[people]

\end{document}
```

Do you know what I must to switch or cancel? Really, I don´t know how obtain the index.

Thank you very much, sincerely!

Comment: Are you running the `makeindex` external program?

Comment: Good question. I´m not sure. How is it runned?

Comment: Usually TeX editors can do it. Search for in some menu.

Comment: I have TeXmaker. Well, I´ve seen it. But still appear an error.

Comment: Error still appear. I think that some commandos goes with "imakeidx", and anothers with "makeidx". Question is to know distinguish

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be `Index` not Bibliography.

Comment: Also, insert `\makeindex` on preamble.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works!  :D   Thank you very much!!